# Understanding the steps in this sum of subarrays algorithm and its run time

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

I've been staring at this for a while and it's not sinking in. I think I understand at a basic level what's going on.  E.g. A = {1, 2, 3, 4}

Sum = A[0] + [A[0] + A[1]] + [A[0] + A[1] + A[2]] + [A[0] + A[1] + A[2] + A[3]]

However, I'm not able to understand the steps via the explanation/notation below - or at least, it's a little fuzzy. Could someone please explain the steps/walk through what's happening.

**Example 1.4 (Sums of subarrays)**. The problem is to compute, for each subarray a[j..j +m−1] of size m in an array a of size n, the partial sum of its elements s[j] = ∑ m−1 k=0 a[j+k]; j = 0,...,n−m. The total number of these subarrays is n−m+1.

At ﬁrst glance, we need to compute n−m+1 sums, each of m items, so that the running time is proportional to m(n−m+1). If m is ﬁxed, the time depends still linearly on n. But if m is growing with n as a fraction of n, such as m = n 2, then T(n) = cn 2n 2 +1= 0.25cn2 +0.5cn. The relative weight of the linear part, 0.5cn, decreases quickly with respect to the quadratic one as n increases.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm having trouble following the notation. I don't understand how exactly it describes the steps taken to execute the algorithm.  Also, I vaguely understand why it has a quadratic run time but not well as I'd like so any clarity would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the explanation, you provided seems to be not about your understanding of the problem. I think, your **Example 1.4** is really about following.

```
A = {1, 2, 3, 4}, m = 3.
Sum = (A[0] + A[1] + A[2]) + (A[1] + A[2] + A[3]).
```

Here you have *n-m+1* (4-3+1=2) subsums of *m*(3) elements each. The described algorithm can be preformed in code like this:

```
function SumOfSubarrays(A, n, m) {
  sum = 0;
  //loop for subarrays
  for (j = 0; j <= n - m; j++;) {

    //loop for elements in each subarray
    for (k = 0; k <= m - 1; k++) {
      sum += A[j + k];
    }
  }
}
```

Time complexity of this algorithm depends linearly on *n*. But, as it is said in **Example 1.4**, if *m* growths as a fraction of *n*, then time complexity becomes quadratic.

You need totally `m(n−m+1)` operations: `(n−m+1)` for outer loop as it is a number of subarrays, `m` for inner loop as it is a number of elements in each subarray. If *m* depends on *n* then you have, for example:

```
m = 0.5 * n
m(n-m+1) = 0.5n(n-0.5n+1) = 0.5n(0.5n-1) = 0.25n^2 - 0.5n
```

Where quadratic part growths faster as it is quadratic.